# Memtest86 tests no errors in test again

Tags: memtest

I started memtest in first pass it showed 15 errors

But i wanted to test again to be deterministic about faulty ram and talk to my laptop shop guy.

In this run i am not able to reproduce errors so what should i say to hardware guy.

Thanks

Comment: Is it new RAM? or just mounted for first time?

Comment: @Sneetsher Its a new Clevo machine , the machine freezes from day 1. I am trying to find if there is something wrong memory or with Ubuntu Nvidia driver :)

Comment: So it new machine, I'm with the advice of @quaeritate. Use Windows and windows RAM test tools for some time. If you can prove problems, take it back.

Answer (score 0):

If it has failed in the past it will likely fail again in the future. Take the ram back and tell him it is faulty. He will either test the RAM or take you at your word.

The only other thing I can think of is it could be a bad power supply. Dodgy power can cause lots of weird hardware problems.

Comment: The system has been freezing again and again and i power off and start again. The clevo people are saying they dont support ubuntu use windows its ubuntu fault.

Comment: Use the Microsoft memory test program then. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.09.utilityspotlight.aspx

Comment: You could also just install windows on it to prove it is faulty. Then get your money back and by a notebook from a nicer supplier.